# How to handle duplicated messages in MQTT with qos 1 using JAVA

Tags: java, mqtt

I am using MQTT message broker to publish and subscribe messages, and I have set QOS to 1. I want to handle duplicate messages without changing QOS level to 2 in Java. 
I tried with isDuplicate() method to check duplicates but could not resolve the issue. How can I handle this case in JAVA?

Comment: That totally depends on your implementation of the protocol. What library are you using?

Comment: I am using java paho client.

Comment: In that case there is no built in solution. You could build a hashCode of the payload + topic and compare this to previous messages to check if you have already recieved this one.

Comment: Other than that there is always QoS2 for exactly that reason: Receive the message exactly once. By not using QoS2 you are saying that you are fine with receiving a message multiple times.

Comment: Why do you not want to use QOS2?

Comment: We tested with QOS2, I felt it is slow. It has to wait until it get acknowledgment back. So, started finding solution in QOS1 itself. Can you explain me, what is the main purpose of isDuplicated()? and Is it possible to use it?

Comment: There are two possible interpretations to your question:
1. You want to handle duplicate messages as a result of the MQTT protocol (built in error correction will resend messages for which no ACK was received), or;
2. You want to handle duplicate messages sent by a client. These messages are not really duplicates (they are completely different MQTT messages from the protocols perspective). They just have the same content.

Which one are you trying to achieve?
Java's `isDuplicate()` method likely provides a way to handle case 1 messages,ie those duplicates generated by the protocol itself.